# How to simulate with and if statement for queuing theory

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm trying to complete an M/M/1 queuing theory simulation in excel. I need to create IF statements which take into consideration the probability of one type of event occuring(out of 4 possible). Used random numbers for arrival time, now trying to get the service time.

Comment: Currently tried using this if statement : =IF(AND(B30>=0, B30<=0.37), 1, IF(AND(B30>=0.37,B30<=0.34),2,IF(AND(B30>=0.34,B30<0.15),3,IF(AND(B30>=0.15,B30<=0.14),4,0))))

Comment: Welcome to So.please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). About your question, do not use comments for updates. Edit your question and add your formula. Add what you have, what you want to get, and what have you tried.